# SFD_CLOEXEC Wayland

Tags: macos, wayland

I'm trying to compile Wayland on OSX Yosemite. I run ./configure and get an error:

```
checking whether SFD_CLOEXEC is declared... no
configure: error: "SFD_CLOEXEC is needed to compile wayland"
```

When I google "SFD_CLOEXEC" It says there are too few results and I can't find even find what SFD_CLOEXEC is. I tried running `brew install SFD_CLOEXEX` and got nothing.

What is SFD_CLOEXEC?

Comment: Curious, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @ybakos Sorry for taking so long, http://papyros.io

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/2/signalfd4

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [this](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-devel-list/2015-January/msg00108.html) answer. It might give you some clues.